# How to style images in reveal.js?

Tags: reveal.js

I am now trying to put transparent png image in reveal.js as:

```
<div class="slides">
    <section>
        <img src="sample.png">
        <p>sample image</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

where figure "sample.png" is follows.

[image]

However, there are:

- white lines appear at the boundary of the figure
- and the figure is not prefect transparent. (contains some white color?)

How can we remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The actual problem is that reveal.js has a style which adds a white background at low opacity, a box-shadow, and a border to images as seen below:

```
.reveal section img { 
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12); 
    border: 4px solid #eeeeee;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 
}
```

So the fix is to override that style with:

```
.reveal section img { background:none; border:none; box-shadow:none; }
```

Comment: Ftr: the style is set in the css of the theme, e.g. `css/theme/black.css`. To override it, I created a `css/custom.css` and included that in the `<head>` of the `index.html` _after_ the theme: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">`.

Comment: If you'd like to modify your personalised style sheet as a .scss the above must come after the line `@import "../template/theme";` if not it will be overriden by the latter

Comment: its 2020 and this is still the perfect solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

In version 3.3.0 there is a class Plain which removes border, shadow and background

```
<img class="plain"  src="myimages.png"/>
```

Answer (score 22):

If you just want to remove this effect on specific images instead of turning it off globally in the CSS file, add the following style attribute to your image tag:

```
<img src="sample.png" style="background:none; border:none; box-shadow:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @cmorrow answer (and the comments), I updated looked into the `css` file, there is an element `.reveal section img.plain` which offers what you want but with a slightly opaque background. I edited that element and included

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
```

and I have the desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

As long as the CSS rules remain the same, then just create your own class and stick it on any image you see fit.

The HTML:

```
<img class="plain" data-src="lib/dist/images/cake_top.png">
```

The StlyleSheet:

```
.reveal section img.plain { background:none; border:none; box-shadow:none; }
```